# When is $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_{t}] =\mathbb{E}\left[X|\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

When is $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_{t}] =\mathbb{E}\left[X|\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$?

Is there a theorem like monotone convergence or dominated convergence for a problem of this sort?

One specific case of interest would be when $\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}$ is a sequence of sub-sigma algebras such that $\forall s<t[\mathcal{F}_{s}\subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t}]$ (that is, it is non-decreasing).

Comment: Presumably the $t$ in the title should be $n$.  You may also want to re-copy the question from the title in the main body. I assumed the $F_n$ was already a filtration as that makes $F_{\infty} = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i$ a natural definitoin. In general, how were you thinking $F_{\infty}$ to be defined?

Comment: Correct, I will do such. Thanks! With respect to the edited comment, $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ should be defined as the limit of $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I changed the notation as it is indeed usually the case that $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ is reserved for that specific case.

Comment: Have a look at Lévy's upward theorem

Comment: @Michael  $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ should not be defined in that way. It may
happen that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_{n}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra
even if $\mathcal{F}_{1}\subseteq\mathcal{F}_{2}\subseteq\ldots$.
In fact, $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ is defined as $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}=\vee_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_{n}:=\sigma\left(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_{n}\right)$.

Comment: @BayesIsBae You need to clarify the meaning of "limit" of $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan : Yes you are right it should be $\sigma(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n)$.

Comment: I did not define the limit in any particular way as I was wondering if there was any general or particular methods of moving the limit under the condition sign just as we have monotonic convergence for integration under the assumption that the series of functions being integrated are monotone. I gave one example of a filtration (which could be thought of as perhaps an analogue of monotonicity).

Comment: (Somewhat off topic, but I want to be sure) @DannyPak-KeungChan $\vee^{\infty}_{n=1}\mathcal{F}_{n}$ is just to say "the maximal sigma algebra over $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$" due to domination ($\mathcal{F}_{1} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{2}$), correct?

Comment: @ BayesIsBae $\vee_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{F}_n$ is just a notation. It denotes the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma\left( \cup_n \mathcal{F}_n \right)$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\cup_n \mathcal{F}_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should state all the premises and define your notations. For example,
let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and let $\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\mid t\geq0\}$
be a filtration. Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable
random variable.

Define $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}=\sigma\left(\cup_{t}\mathcal{F}_{t}\right)$.
For each $t\geq0$, note that $E\left[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$
is only determined a.e. What is the sense of convergence $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}E\left[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$
? Pointwisely a.e. ?

If this is what you want, you need to be careful: For the case of
sequence, if we want to talk about pointwise a.e. convergence $X_{n}\rightarrow X$,
for each $n$, we may modify $X_{n}$ on a $P$-null set and it would
not affect the conclusion. However, for limit process involving uncountably
terms, like $X_{t}\rightarrow X$, we are not allow to "For each
$t$, modify $X_{t}$ on a $P$-null set". Now, we immediately encounter
a problem: What is $E[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}]$? It is not a concrete
random variable, but it is only determined a.e.. It is true that $\{E[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}]\mid t\geq0\}$
is always a martingale. However, its sample paths are out of control.
Note that, if the filtration is standard, we can always choose a cadlag
modification for $\{E[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}]\mid t\geq0\}$ (a deep
result due to Doob) then invoke Martingale Convergence Theorem (uniformly
integrable version) and conclude that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}E[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}]=E[X\mid\mathcal{F}_{\infty}]$
pointwisely a.e.